# How to get update information of Microsoft Edge Extensions

Tags: microsoft-edge, webview2

I can download every Microsoft Edge Add-On (Web extension) as a .crx file by using this URL:

[https://edge.microsoft.com/extensionwebstorebase/v1/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3D[EXTENSION_ID]%26installsource%3Dondemand%26uc](https://edge.microsoft.com/extensionwebstorebase/v1/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3D%5BEXTENSION_ID%5D%26installsource%3Dondemand%26uc)

[EXTENSION_ID] is the ID like "elhekieabhbkpmcefcoobjddigjcaadp" for [this](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/adobe-acrobat-werkzeuge-/elhekieabhbkpmcefcoobjddigjcaadp) Add-on.

I use this for using in a [WebView2](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/microsoft-edge/webview2/) control.

But before downloading an update, I would like to check, if an update of the Add-on is available.

**How can I get version information of available Edge Add-ons?**

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no API to obtain Edge extension version information, you can refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/api-support.

Comment: What do you mean with "Extension store"? I would like to get the version programmatically inside my app, running on a users machine.